# CSS cutting text and numbers

Tags: javascript, css, text, format

I have a large text "desoxyribonucleic" and number 0.4234 or 0.352352523

So I need such format of represent it:

text: desoxyribon...
number: 0.42
number: 0.35

Is it real to roll out this with CSS?
Thanx!

Comment: Fixed width and overflow:hidden

Comment: Do you need to deal with rounding as well? If so, you can't use CSS alone for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup!

```css
.ellipsis {
    max-width: 100px; /* adjust as needed */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* magic happens here */
}
```

For numbers, you can try using `someNumber.toFixed(2)` in JavaScript, just be careful of rounding.

Comment: someNumber.toFixed(2) works well, but ellipisi doesnt work maybe because i`m using d3.js for text building